# Delete records using Email Service between 2 integrated S2S orgs

Tags: apex-email-service, salesforce2salesforce

I have two S2S integrated orgs which are sharing Lead's records succefully. I have implemented the same using Apex and Salesforce to Salesforce Connections. My requirement is if a record is deleted from Source org, that record (already shared through S2S integration) should automatically delete from target org using Email Services. I have created a trigger and class in Source org which is sending the mail after record deletion. However the record is not being deleted from Target org. I have written an Email Handler class and called the same in Email Service at Target org, however I think there is some issue with the Email Handler class with respect to mapping. Kindly suggest.

Source Org's Trigger-

```
trigger EmailAfterDelete on Lead(after delete) { 

      HelperLeadTriggerNew.sendEmail(trigger.old); // Calling Helper class

}
```

Source Org's Helper Class-

```
public with sharing class HelperLeadTriggerNew {
public static List <Lead> sendEmail(List<Lead> lds){


List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for (Lead ld : lds) {    
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    email.setToAddresses(new String[] {'abc@gmail.com'});
    email.setSubject('Deleted Lead Alert Lead: ' + ld.Name + '');
    email.setPlainTextBody('This message is to alert you that the Lead named ' + ld.Name + ' has been deleted.');
    emails.add(email);
}
Messaging.sendEmail(emails);

return lds;
 }
}
```

Till now everything is working fine.

Target Org's Email Handler Class

```
global class myHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
      Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
      return result;
  }
 public static List <Lead> sendEmail(List<Lead> lds){

    List<Lead> ld = new List<Lead>();
for(Lead l : lds)
{
    Lead led = new Lead();
    led.Name = alName;
    ld.add(led);
}


delete ld;    
return null;    
  }
}
```

Debug Logs at Target Org-

```
23:36:18.049 (49930877)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p28000001QqZA|emailToLead.handleInboundEmail
23:36:18.051 (51494513)|METHOD_ENTRY|[1]|01p28000001QqZA|emailToLead.emailToLead()
23:36:18.051 (51506131)|METHOD_EXIT|[1]|emailToLead
23:36:18.052 (52620646)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[5]|System.debug(ANY)
23:36:18.052 (52657955)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|abc Deleted Lead Alert Lead: Test 54
23:36:18.052 (52668252)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[5]|System.debug(ANY)
23:36:18.053 (53002823)|SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[6]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id FROM Lead WHERE Name = :tmpVar1 LIMIT 1
23:36:18.062 (62675940)|SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[6]|Rows:0
23:36:18.062 (62970324)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject

Class.emailToLead.handleInboundEmail: line 6, column 1
23:36:18.062 (62987385)|FATAL_ERROR|System.QueryException: List has no rows for assignment to SObject
```

Comment: I can see you have a method named sendEmail(List<Lead> lds) on the inbound email handler. But where is that method getting called? Also how do you identintify which leads are to be deleted on the inbound email handler? are you using some regex to do it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.... I need to identify and delete the leads which have the same "Name" in both orgs. I know there are lots of issues in the Ema handler class. Could you please help me with a sample code for the same so that I can try it in my org.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In email subject you can give lead name as well. And in handleInboundEmail() method you can retrieve lead name from subject:

```
global class myHandler implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
    global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {

    String leadName = email.subject;
    Lead leadToDelete = [Select id from Lead where Name IN :leadName];
    Delete leadToDelete;

    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
    return result;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to give lead name in subject, then you can extract lead name from body using string methods and then do the same as above.

Hope this may help.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help.... I tried your code however, when checked in debug logs, the Subject is picking up the Lead Name but it is not deleting the same. It shows Name as ' SELECT Name FROM Account WHERE Name = :tmpVar1 '

Comment: Yes you got right, there is a small syntax issue. This must work:
Lead leadToDelete = [Select id from Lead where Name = :leadName];

Comment: I already made that correction but its giving the same error and record is not getting deleted. Please help.

Comment: Can you please give the code & error which you are getting.

Comment: Heres the code- "global class emailToLead implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {
  global Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) {
String LeadName = email.subject;
    Lead ldToDelete = [Select id from Lead where Name = :LeadName];
System.debug ('abc' + ldToDelete);   
    Delete ldToDelete;
System.debug ('xyz' + ldToDelete);
Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();
  return result;
  }
}"       and the debug log says "SELECT id FROM Lead WHERE Name = :tmpVar1"

Comment: There is no error, only the record is not getting deleted.

Comment: Did you checked manually that lead record exists in your target org with same name as subject and if it is being deleted when the inbound handler runs. Also replace the query with this and try : 
   
   Lead ldToDelete = [Select id from Lead where Name = :LeadName Limit 1];

Comment: No luck. I replaced the query as per suggestion but its still gives the same debug log. I am checking the records manually and they are not getting deleted from Target org with the same Names.

Comment: Did you checked in you debug log whether its returning any lead record from query. Please check rows after query in debug log. Its seems very strange.

Comment: I am attaching the main lines of the log with the original question. "Test 54" is the Name of Lead which is being printed on subject line. Please check. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so from the debug log you attached it shows "List has no rows for assignment to SObject", that means it is not able to find any lead record with the subject name. Can you give that code line from you class "HelperLeadTriggerNew" where you are specifying subject.

Comment: email.setSubject('Deleted Lead Alert Lead: ' + ld.Name + '');       I checked the same in debug logs at Source Org and subject line is printing the Lead's Name.

Comment: Ok that is the issuse. Actually query is trying to find a lead record with same name as subject which is "Deleted Lead Alert Lead: LEADNAME". Either you only give lead name in your subject or you have to extract the exact lead name from your subject using string methods and then pass that extracted lead name in query.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs... Im trying with mentioning only the Lead Name. Will update with the progress...

Comment: It worked :) I mentioned only the Name in subject and it deleted the record from both the orgs. However when checked the debug logs in Target org, there was no class showing up that ran after deleting the record in Source org. Is that fine?

Comment: sounds gr8, yes that is fine because there is no after delete trigger on lead object in target org which can call a class.

Comment: Ya there is no trigger in Target Org.... Again thanks a bunch for your help.... You made my day :)

Comment: m glad I was able to help you, u r welcome.. :)

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA